# no consigo instalar correctamente Oracle database 21c

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, windows10, instalacion

Tengo un problema al instalar Oracle database 21c en mi equipo con win10 pro.
En el proceso de instalación casi al final hace un roll back y finaliza con el mensaje que se instalo con errores.
He probado todo lo que me dice internet reiniciando Windows, borrando la variable de entorno y demás pero sigue sin funcionar...como puedo solucionarlo? muchas gracias de antemano.-

```
En la carpeta cfgtoollogs que me genero la instalación fallida tengo un log con esto: O/S-Error: (OS 1387) No se puede agregar ni quitar un miembro del grupo local porque el miembro no existe.
INFORMACIÓN: Excepción devuelta de la acción: AddInstallUserToGroup
Nombre de la Excepción: WindowsSecurityException has occurred
Cadena de la Excepción: Failed to add NOTEBOOK\NOTEBOOK install user to %2% group.
Gravedad de la Excepción: 0
INFO:  [09/01/2022 19:58:34] Adding ExitStatus STOP_INSTALL to the exit status set
INFO:  [09/01/2022 19:58:34] Finding the most appropriate exit status for the current application
INFO:  [09/01/2022 19:58:34] inventory location isC:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory
INFO:  [09/01/2022 19:58:34] Finding the most appropriate exit status for the current application
INFO:  [09/01/2022 19:58:34] Exit Status is -4
INFO:  [09/01/2022 19:58:34] Shutdown Instalador de Oracle Database 21c
INFO:  [09/01/2022 19:58:34] Unloading Setup Driver
```

Comment: no hay un log que nos puedas mostrar? si no, es dificil saber que pueda estar pasando...

Comment: ¿Has ejecutado el instalador con permisos de administrador?

Comment: Si lo he ejecutado como admin

Answer (score 1):

Tenía el mismo error y aunque el log no lo detallase pensé que podría ser por mi nombre de usuario, ya que contiene un caracter especial (tilde), creé un nuevo usuario administrador sin la tilde y ya lo he instalado correctamente,
espero que te funcione :)

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/366006)